# Set array in one php file and access in another php file issue

Tags: php, css, extract

I'm using [this php code](http://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-php-dynamic) code to write out my css with populated variables.

I want to move the default array out of this code and lift it to a `settings.php` file for my site but when I do I get this error message:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  extract() [<a href='function.extract'>function.extract</a>]: First argument should be an array in <b>/home/drawapl1/public_html/ezamazon/demo/css/stylesheet.php</b> on line <b>19</b>
```

My code is as follows:

in index.php:

```
<?php
include("settings.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/stylesheet.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

in stylesheet.php:

```
/* get the stylesheet */
$stylesheet = @is_file($_GET['stylesheet']) && strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1)) == 'css' ? $_GET['stylesheet'] : 'global.css';

/* set the header information */
//will be output as css
header('Content-type: text/css');
//set an expiration date
$days_to_cache = 10;
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * $days_to_cache)).' GMT');

//red css variable information
//$red = array(
  //'body_font_size' => '10px',
  //'body_text_color' => '#f00'
//);

/* extract the propery array's information */
extract($_GET['theme'] && ${$_GET['theme']} ? ${$_GET['theme']} : $defaultCSS);

/* load in the stylesheet */
$content = preg_replace('/\$([\w]+)/e','$0',@file_get_contents($stylesheet));

/* spit it out */
echo $content;
```

in settings.php:

`$defaultCSS = array(
  'body_background_colour' => 'white',
  'body_text_colour' => 'black',
  'body_font_size' => '1em',
  'body_font_family' => 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
  'h1_text_colour' => 'black',
  'h2_text_colour' => 'black',
  'h3_text_colour' => '#E47911',
  'a_text_colour' => '#004B91',
  'a_hover_text_colour' => '#2A70FC',
  'news_block_background_colour' => '#EAF3FE',
  'left_nav_border_colour' => '#C9E1F4',
  'left_nav_h2_background_colour' => '#EAF3FE',
  'button_text_colour' => '#FFFFFF',
  'button_background_colour' => '#414953',
  'button_hover_background_colour' => '#999999',
  'price_colour' => '#990000',
  'price_heading_colour' => '#666666',
  'nav_links_colour' => 'black',
  'nav_hover_links_colour' => '#E47911',
  'hr_divider_colour' => '#DDDDDD',
  'pagination_highlight_colour' => '#645538'
);`

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you what actual code **you** use?

Comment: What does your code look like, does `settings.php` get loaded before the style-sheet php?

Comment: `${$_GET['theme']}` isn't an array. Can you echo out the value of `$_GET['theme']` and post here?

Comment: We'll need to see some code so we can make sense of the error message.  Also, have you considered just using [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)?

Comment: I have update with the actual code. I didn't post this originally as there is quite a lot of it and I thought maybe I could explain it without it. If I echo $_GET['theme'] I don't see anything. Using require instead of include for settings.php doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using `include()` to include `settings.php` before everything.

The most likely reason this isn't working is that the file doesn't know see a `$default` variable, and creates a new `null` variable for the parameter.

Try this:

```
//settings.php

  /* set the dynamic information */
  //default css variable information
  $default = array(
    'body_font_size' => '16px',
    'body_text_color' => '#00f'
  );

//main_php_file.php

  include('settings.php'); // This is the important part

  /* extract the propery array's information */
  extract($_GET['theme'] && ${$_GET['theme']} ? ${$_GET['theme']} : $default);
```

Also try `print_r($default)` after `include('settings.php');` to make sure that `$default` is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Including settings.php in the index.php file and then calling stylesheet.php from within your html document will not pass the variables in settings.php to stylesheet.php

You need to include settings.php in stylesheet.php to be able to use it's variables there.

**EDIT**

In index.php

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.php?vars=<?=urlencode(json_encode($defaultCSS))?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

in stylesheet.php add at the top

```
$defaultCSS = json_decode(urldecode($_GET['vars']));
```

you could also use serialize/unserialize instead of json_encode - but why not just include it, it's much cleaner to keep it all server side

Comment: Is there anyway to pass them across with session or something?